# Storing and Displaying String from SQLite to MainActivity

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android, just days old to SQLite Database.

In my application, I need to store 10 Strings in database, that I can display on the Main Activity, one string at a time and the string will change on the swipe.

I am following [`AndroidHive`](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/), but its not working for me.

I can do the swipe part myself, but can anybody suggest me the method or even some good links regarding storing strings into db?  It will very helpful.

*Of all the tutorial that i am reading, they all are showing me how to allow user to put something into database where as what i want to already store the string into the database.

MainActivity:

```
String quotes1 = "My name is Bhanu";
String quotes2 = "My name is Rahul";
String quotes3 = "My name is not Bhanu";
String quotes4 = "My name is not Rahul";
String quotes5 = "My name is Anil";
String quotes6 = "My name is not Anil";
    int counter;
    Button choosenext;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter=0;
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaytext);
        choosenext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_choose);
        choosenext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is a good tutorial i followed.

Comment: http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tutorial for beginners I know is [Android SQLite database and content provider](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial).
It is very well explained. Follow the steps. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: The onUpgrade() method simply delete all existing data and re-create the table but in my application once I save the strings into db, there will be no upgradations in it.So, is there is any need to declare onUpgrade() method ??

Comment: @bhanukaushik there is no need to call onupgrade()..if in your project databse structure is not change....

Comment: @dipali one more thing, I have to store 10 strings into the db and i only want 1 string at a time on the MainActivty. For this i am setting a counter=0, with each swipe I am increasing it making the next string to display on MainActivity. Is it right, what I am trying to implement ??

Comment: @bhanukaushik in your db you have to store 10 string?

Comment: If these strings will never change and all you need is 10 strings then you can use string-array

Comment: @Minas how will i change the strings on the swipe ?? like if its displaying "mercury" and on a swipe it will change to the next item i.e Venus in this case

Comment: You can get the array in java code String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);   and get any element by index, eg.  planets[0]

Comment: @Minas just out of curosity, Can I implement this method to display 500 strings ?

Comment: @bhanu kaushik  Yes, there is no limit. For example in one of my apps I have a string-array with around 100 smileys.

Comment: @Minas one last query. I have updated my MainActivity.java . Can you please tell me how to display the second string on the press of button .

Comment: Instead of separate strings make a string array, in onClick add  counter++;  display.setText(quotes[counter]);

Answer (score 1):

### [From this link you'll learn that you want.](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android/)

For Dummy this [TUTORIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) is best to understand easily.

### [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

### [Android Local SQLite Database Example](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/)

### [Android SQLite Database](http://javapapers.com/android/android-sqlite-database/)

### [Android | Simple SQLite Database Tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

and now for more stuff you have to search on [**Google like this.**](http://bit.ly/NssZuN)